# Access annotation attributes from custom oval annotation

Tags: java, oval

Is it possible, when using custom oval annotation and custom class for check, to access the annotation and retrieve the used annotation attributes ?

Reference for oval: https://sebthom.github.io/oval/USERGUIDE.html#custom-constraint-annotations

---

**Minimal example**

Lets assume we have class `Foo`.
It has two annotated fields.
Each time, the annotation has a different `myValue` – `a` and `b`.

```
class Foo {
  @CustomAnnotation(myValue = "a")
  public String first;

  @CustomAnnotation(myValue = "b")
  public String second;
}
```

This is the annotation.
It is noted that a check should be performed using `MyCheck.class`, also setting some default value for `myValue`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Constraint(checkWith = MyCheck.class)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String myValue() default "";
}
```

Now we want to use oval to validate this field.
Most importantly, we want to extract the value `a` or `b` from the annotation's `myValue` and use it inside our validation logic.

```java
public class MyCheck extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<CustomAnnotation> {


    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object valueToValidate, OValContext context,
                               Validator validator) throws OValException {
  // how to get the value of `myValue`, which is `a` or `b` or empty string as default
  }
}
```

What I have tried and failed:

1. `validatedObject` is `Foo.class`. You can easily get its fields and annotations. However, there is no way to differentiate between the two annotations.
2. `valueToValidate` is in this case `String` value – what `first` or `second` holds.
3. `context` not useful, you can get compile time type from it, which is `String`
4. `validator` not useful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the superclass I have found that you can override method

- `configure`

This method gets as the only parameter the annotation that is currently being checked at the field.
You can then read the `myValue`.

```java
public class MyCheck extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<CustomAnnotation> {

    private String myValue;

    @Override
    public void configure(CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) {
        super.configure(customAnnotation);
        this.myValue = customAnnotation.myValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object valueToValidate, OValContext context,
                               Validator validator) throws OValException {
        if (myValue.equals("a")) {}
        else if (myValue.equals("b")){}
        else {}
}
```